# Select three rows of text in PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, adobe

I am trying to use VBA to select three rows of data in a PDF file and copy them to the clipboard. I have tried third party libraries but I still can't seem to find a simple solution. I can use the cursor to select the data and copy it, so I just want to automate this step with VBA.

I have looked high and low for an answer to this and I feel like it might be really simple and I'm just missing it. I assume I could just use the "highliteList" method in the acrobat library to select the rows, but I don't know how to specify where to begin the selection. There is a header on each page, so I just want to say something like:
    For Each header In pdf.pages
        NextLine.SelectRow
        NextLine.SelectRow
    Next header
    Selection.CopyToClipboard

Is this possible? I know those methods probly don't exist, I was using it as an example. Does anyone have experience with doing this? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for all those interested. I used Bytescout PDF extractor library to convert the file to .xls format. Then I just parsed out what I needed in Excel since Excel is easy to work with via vb.net.